# Why priorityQueue is not sorting the elements

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue

I have below piece of code

```
        Comparator<StudentDTO> compareNames = Comparator.comparing(StudentDTO::getName);
    PriorityQueue<StudentDTO> h = new PriorityQueue<>(compareNames);

    h.offer(new StudentDTO(5, "c"));
    h.offer(new StudentDTO(2, "b"));
    h.offer(new StudentDTO(8, "z"));
    h.offer(new StudentDTO(1, "a"));
```

System.out.println(h);

And I am getting output as below:

```
[StudentDTO [rollNo=1, Name=a], StudentDTO [rollNo=2, Name=b], StudentDTO [rollNo=8, Name=z], StudentDTO [rollNo=5, Name=c]]
```

Not sure why Name=z is coming before Name=c.
Edit: I am using java 8.

Answer (score 3):

When you print `PriorityQueue` like this - the `toString` method from `AbstractCollection` is invoked underneath. And it uses `Iterator` of the extending colllection - in your case of the `PriorityQueue` - to travers the collection and create a `String` from it. And if you check the docs of [`PriorityQueue::iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) it returns iterator that returns elements in no particular order :

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

If you want to retrive elements in their priority order defined by comparator use methods like `poll` and `remove`. Considering you have overriden `StudentDTO::toString method` something like this will print objects from the queue also removing them from the queue :

```
while (!h.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(h.poll());
}
```

and the output :

```
StudentDTO{rollNo=1, name='a'}
StudentDTO{rollNo=2, name='b'}
StudentDTO{rollNo=5, name='c'}
StudentDTO{rollNo=8, name='z'}
```